# NBA2k11 Wii - Right Stick Passing

Tags: nintendo-wii, nba2k11

Is anyone able to use right stick passing on NBA 2k11 for Wii? I tried displaying the icon pass icons, by pressing Zr, and then flicking with the right stick, but it results (always) in a shot to the basket. I'm using a Classic Controller.